# Using a Template for Web Page

Tags: asp.net, html, templates, web, master-pages

We have a fairly large public website and have recently redsigned it with a new layout.  The problem now is that with our redesign we find ourselves constantly hardcoding the html layout for all of our pages.  This is clearly not the best solution.

My question is what are some options on ways to share/inherit, in a sense, a web template that all our ASP.Net projects can pull from for the layout.  Specifically the HTML side of the layout.  Any changes made to this template will update all web sites that use it.  I'm sure this exists but do not know how to approach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Master Pages is what you are looking for. See: http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials
or http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/creating-a-site-wide-layout-using-master-pages-vb

That's the technical solution. Oftentimes, the bigger challenge in retrofitting sites that were built with numerous one-offs is determining which parts of your pages belong in the master page or content areas. Keep in mind that you can have multiple content areas and you can provide default content in a master page that can later be overriden in a content page. It's very flexible. Have fun!

Comment: +1, plus I'd point out that you can nest your master pages in other master pages, giving you even more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach I know is to create a header and footer file for every page.  Include the header just after the `<body>` tag and the footer just before `</body>`.  You content goes in between.

I prefer a more sophisticated approach with a templating system like Smarty, but that's PHP.  I don't know what your ASP options are.